# Problem with routes.mapper package in python - generate is returning None for some reason?

Tags: python, routes, mapping

I'm using the python Routes package (http://routes.groovie.org/modules/mapper.html#routes.mapper.Mapper.connect)

And i've simplified my code down to the following:

```
from routes import Mapper
m = Mapper()
m.connect('upnp/:udn/:sid/:action', controller='upnp', action='desc', sid=None)
a = m.generate(controller='upnp', action='desc', udn='uuid:1234', sid=None)
print '---'
print a
print '---'
```

Now, i think it should print out '/upnp/uuid:1234/None/desc' but generate returns None.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why: the sid=None in the generate line.